# MouseButtonEventArgs.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver misunderstanding

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, mouseevent

I was faced with the next misunderstanding.

**Preamble**:

I have wpf application with next essential UI parts: `RadioButtons` and some control that use dropdown based on `Popup` (in combobox manner). According to some logic every radiobutton hook `PreviewMouseDown` event and do some calculations. 
In the next scenario,

1. User opens popup (do not select something, popup just staying open)
2. User click on radiobutton

`PreviewMouseDown` will not be fired for radiobutton as expected (because of `Popup` [feature](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9337ff73-0641-4336-a65b-5aeb3a1ad3d8/)).

And my aim is firing `PreviewMouseDown` for `RadioButton` despite of one.

**Attempts to solve**:

Fast and dirty solution is: hook `PreviewMouseDown` for `Popup` and re-fire `PreviewMouseDown` event with new source if required, using radiobutton as source. New source can be obtained via `MouseButtonEventArgs.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver`. The next piece of code do that (event is re-fired only if `Popup` "eat" `PreviewMouseDown` for outer click):

```
    private static void GrantedPopupPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = sender as Popup;
        if(popup == null)
            return;

        var realSource = e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver as FrameworkElement;
        if(realSource == null || !realSource.IsLoaded)
            return;

        var parent = LayoutTreeHelper.GetParent<Popup>(realSource);

        if(parent == null || !Equals(parent, popup ))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            var args = new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice,
                                                e.Timestamp,
                                                e.ChangedButton)
            {
                RoutedEvent = UIElement.PreviewMouseDownEvent,
                Source = e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver,
            };
            realSource.RaiseEvent(args);
        }
    }
```

This **works well** when I'm attaching that handler to `Popup.PreviewMouseDown` directly via `Behavior` and **do not work** (`PreviewMouseDown` isn't fired for radiobutton) if I'm attaching one via `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler` (aim is to avoid attaching behavior to every `Popup` that can occure on page with these radiobuttons):

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
            typeof (Popup),
            PreviewMouseDownEvent,
            new MouseButtonEventHandler(GrantedPopupPreviewMouseDown));
```

Debugger showed that `e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver` (see code above) is `Popup`, not `Radiobutton` (as it is was when I've attached handler via `Behavior`)!

**Question**:

How and why`MouseButtonEventArgs` can be different for the same action, if eventhandler attached in two different ways?

Can someone explaing this behavior?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a minimal reproducible test case in XAML for that for us to play? There might be a confusion about what Preview means in WPF context. As Preview*Events are tunneling events and you may want to use the MouseDown Event as it is per default bubbling up your visual tree

Comment: Can you post the XAML for your Popup and RadioButton?  Like Samuel said, this is a problem with tunneling vs bubbling events.  The event is getting handled on the Popup before it can even reach the Radiobutton is my guess.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but would something like this work? - MouseDown event handler for popup => popup.Close(); MouseUp event handler for radiobutton => do your thing. The idea being that a MouseClick consists of two actions, the first MouseDown action would close the popup, and the second MouseUp action would then be captured by the radio button...

Comment: Have you tried playing with IsHitTestVisible Property? http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/ishittestvisible/

Answer (score 0):

The combo box is provided as a way for users to select from a group of options, and you likely want to do that.  But it also has other contracts.  It says that the user should be focused on this and only this task.  But that is not your situation.  You want to show the options, have them hide able, and allow the user to do other things while they are shown.

I think instead of combo boxes you want some other control.  My suggestion is to use an expander that contains a listbox.  Given:

```
class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

class ComboEntry : NotificationObject
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private string _option = "Off";
    public string Option 
    {
        get { return _option; }
        set { _option = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Option"); }
    }

    public ComboEntry()
    {
        Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}

class MyDataContext : NotificationObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<ComboEntry> Entries { get; private set; }

    private ComboEntry _selectedEntry;
    public ComboEntry SelectedEntry
    {
        get { return _selectedEntry; }
        set { _selectedEntry = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEntry"); }
    }
    public MyDataContext()
    {
        Entries = new ObservableCollection<ComboEntry>
        {
            new ComboEntry(),
            new ComboEntry(),
            new ComboEntry()
        };
        SelectedEntry = Entries.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public void SetOption(string value)
    {
        Entries
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(entry => entry.Option = value);
    }
}
```

I think you want the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="RadioInCombo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadioInCombo"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyDataContext x:Key="myDataContext" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboEntryTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Border Width="5" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Option}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource myDataContext}">
        <RadioButton x:Name="OnButton"
                     Content="On"
                     PreviewMouseDown="OnButton_PreviewMouseDown" />
        <RadioButton x:Name="OffButton"
                     Content="Off"
                     PreviewMouseDown="OffButton_PreviewMouseDown" />
        <Expander Header="{Binding SelectedEntry}" 
                  HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ComboEntryTemplate}">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboEntryTemplate}" />
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the following code-behind:

```
    private MyDataContext GetMyDataContext()
    {
        var candidate = FindResource("myDataContext") as MyDataContext;
        if (candidate == null) throw new ApplicationException("Could not locate the myDataContext object");
        return candidate;
    }

    private void OnButton_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        GetMyDataContext().SetOption("On");            
    }

    private void OffButton_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        GetMyDataContext().SetOption("Off");
    }
```